# How to install Nemo on Ubuntu (deb package)

Tags: filemanager, nemo

I've been using the Nautilus file manager for the xfce4 desktop environment. I dislike it. Can anyone tell me how to get Nemo for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *comparatively* easy to install the Nemo file manager under Ubuntu, and the technique needs only a few small modifications to run with the Xfce4 desktop. Two simple steps are required:

**1. Install Xfce4 and Nemo...**

As you have probably found the 'lightest' way to install Xfce4 from a standard Ubuntu installation is to simply run:

```
sudo apt install xfce4
```

And then select 'Xfce Session' at the login screen. From there you can install Nemo (and a considerable number of Nemo's friends) as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install nemo
```

This will install the Nemo file manager which will be easily accessible from the Xfce4 menu.

**2. Make Nemo the default...**

You will note that Thunar will still be the *default* file manager and for completion this should be altered to Nemo. Run the command:

```
exo-preferred-applications
```

from a Terminal screen and alter the Preferred File Manager to Nemo as I demonstrate in the following screenshot:

[image]

Now you can successfully use Nemo for all of your File Manage needs under Ubuntu running Xfce4. It is wonderful to have so many choices when you are running Linux!!

**3. Celebrate with a screenshot...**

Below is a gratuitous screenshot demonstrating Nemo with Xfce4 running on my own system:

[image]